# Initialize Block RAM with file which contain ASCII data

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I want to initialize Block RAM with text file which contain ASCII data like "AGCCT", Is there any idea how can I do this?
I am able to initialize BRAM with file which contain binary or hexadecimal data but I don not know how to initialize it with ASCII file. I want to implement this code on FPGA so I need to use syntax which is synthesizable.

Comment: I do not want to convert ASCII file to a Hex file. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

I think converting ASCII to hex/binary file and then use of `$readmemb` or `$readmemh` would serve your purpose.

```
reg [3:0] memory [15:0] ;
initial begin
  $readmemb("data.bin", memory) ;
end
```